# Angular 8: How to send click event to specific coordinate

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing

I want to know how to send click event to a specific coordinate on the screen,for example to pixel (700,700) in angular?

I searched this question and found solutions only for pure javascript where you can use document element, but you cant do this in angular 8.

My original problem is:
I have a div element which has a click event, the callback of the click event check if it clicked on specific area, if it does, it will minimize the div. 
So i want to write a unit-test, and send click events to that div.

How can i do that?
Thanks in ahead.

Comment: Sounds like [triggerEventHandler](https://angular.io/guide/testing#clicking) since coordinates can change on responsive apps.

Comment: If the click is bound to a function through angular, can't that function be tested without the click event?

Comment: @fingeron The event handler is examining the event...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it works for me:

Inside my unit-test:

```
let section = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('.data-wrapper'))[0];
const mouseDblEvent = new MouseEvent('dblclick', <MouseEventInit>{ clientX: 700, clientY: 700 }) ;

section.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(mouseDblEvent);
fixture.detectChanges();
```

The main idea here was to create MouseEvent with initail parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I hope i understand you correctly ...

if you want to fire click on spesific div, you can use 
`@ViewChild('YOUR_DIV_ID', {static: true}) div;`

and then, on your test, you can trigger a click event - `div.nativeElement.click()`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but Im sorry, its not what i mean. I mean, so you raise a click event on the div, great. But how you make the click to be on pixel (700,700)? like "make a click event on pixel(x, y)" . Its relevant to me...

Comment: maybe you can use `document.elementFromPoint(700, 700)` and if the element exist fire an event ?

Comment: I think its problematic to use document object in angular. I think we need to use it only in pure javascript. I finally found something for angular, its simply just create a MouseEvent object with initial parameters :)

Answer (score -1):

If you have the `(click)` event on the div, then add this to the component to get the coordinates:

```
onClickEvent(event: MouseEvent) {
  const x = event.offsetX,
  const y = event.offsetY
}
```

Comment: OP knows how to get coordinates, they're asking how to fake a click at a specific coordinate